# How do I remove IntelliJ's blank line numbers?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

IntelliJ 2022.1 is showing blank line numbers above @s and methods.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-291945).

Since the issue is usually caused by the long refresh from the VCS, it should help if you disable this option:

Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Inlay Hints | Code Vision | **Code authors**.

[image: Code author]

Other possible workarounds:

- disable Subversion integration
- add `editor.codeVision.new=false` at Help | Edit Custom Properties and restart the IDE.

The fix will be available in the next IDE update.

Answer (score 10):

Go to Settings then Editor then Inlay Hints and disable Inheritors, Usages, and Code author

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it is driving me crazy!