# Blank lines in Android Studio Electric Eel

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-electric-eel

I recently updated Android Studio to the Electric Eel version and I noticed that the editor shows black lines even where there shouldn't be any. Seems like a waste of workspace space to me but I couldn't find anything in the settings.

Android Studio:

[image: Android Studio]

Notepad:

[image: Notepad]

Does any of you have the same problem ?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71877053/how-do-i-remove-intellijs-blank-line-numbers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove IntelliJ's blank line numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71877053/how-do-i-remove-intellijs-blank-line-numbers)

Comment: @d.u.a.l yes, see my comment below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Settings > Editor > Inlay Hints: i have disabled Inheritors, Usages and Code author.

Thanks to Zain.

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 0):

You can :
Change your theme and restart with clear cache android studio.