# Empty spaces in-between lines added after updating Android Studio to 2022.1.1 Patch 1

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Empty spaces are added to the editor after updating to the last version.
look at lines 114-115
how to disable it?

*Apple M1 chip Android studio 2022.1.1 Patch 1*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-291945), please check related SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71877053/how-do-i-remove-intellijs-blank-line-numbers).
You can try to use a newer version of Android Studio (from 2022.2), or the workaround mentioned in the above post:

Disable **Code author** option in **Settings (MacOS: ⌘ + ,  Win/Linux: Ctrl + Alt +S) > Editor > Inlay Hints > Code Vision**.